# Implementing a function of a templated interface with pointer as return type -> Conflicting return type error

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, gcc, return-type

I'm currently learning C++ and have come across the following problem: I have a templated interface BaseTemplate, which I would like to implement in a Child class without making the child a template itself. Sample code is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class BaseTemplate
{
    public:
        virtual const T get() const = 0;
};

class Child : public BaseTemplate<int*>
{
    public:
        Child(int value) : myInt{value} {};
        virtual const int* get() const override { return &myInt; };

    private:
        int myInt{0};
};

int main()
{
    Child myChild = Child(10);
    std::cout << myChild.get() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

GCC produces the following error:

```
main.cpp|16|error: conflicting return type specified for ‘virtual const int* Child::get() const’
main.cpp|9|note: overridden function is ‘const T BaseTemplate<T>::get() const [with T = int*]’
```

I clearly understand that the error is related to
`virtual const int* get() const override { return &myInt; };` but I don't understand what's the problem. If I change the return type (of course in both classes) to `int`, i. e. return a value instead of a pointer, it works fine. So what's wrong with pointers here?

Maybe it helps: in my actual code, I want return a pointer to a custom interface instead of int, the error there is related I believe

```
file_trees.h|19|error: invalid covariant return type for ‘virtual const IDirectoryNode* FileTree::DepthFirstIterator::getCurrent() const’
iterator_interface.h|10|note: overridden function is ‘const T IIterator<T>::getCurrent() const [with T = IDirectoryNode*]’
```

Answer (score 3):

It has to due how `const` applies to types.

`const T` means the returned value is constant (that is of course almost useless). For pointers, this means the pointer itself is constant, not its target.

On the other hand, `const int*` is a non-constant pointer to a `const int` value.

For `Base<int*>`, `T=int*` yields `int* const`, not `const* int`, so you have to define `int* const get()` virtual method.

For `T=const int*` it would be `const int* const`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const) for more details.

Comment: I kinda see the problem. So if my intention was to have a pointer to a constant value (i. e. protect the value from beeing changed through the pointer), the easiest would be to make my abstract definition `virtual T get() const = 0;` and use `const int*` as my template typename, i. e. `Child : public BaseTemplate<const int*>` with `virtual const int* get() const override {...}`. Right? That looks also more elegant to me.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a

```
int *
```

The constant version of this type is not `const int *`. It is `int * const`, or a constant pointer to an `int`.  `const int *` is a pointer to a constant `int`, which is a completely different type.

However, fixing the return type is insufficient, because `get()` is a `const` class method. Taking a pointer to it's data pointer produces a `const int *`, rather than an `int *`.

Probably the simplest fix here is to make this class member mutable:

```cpp
class Child : public BaseTemplate<int*>
{
    public:
        Child(int value) : myInt{value} {};
        virtual int *const get() const override { return &myInt; };

    private:
        mutable int myInt{0};
};
```

Without fundamentally redesigning the entire class hierarchy, this is the minimal fix to get this to compile. You should fully understand what it means to make a class member `mutable`, and understand all implications.

Comment: I think I didn't make my intention very clear. I don't want a constant pointer, I want to protect the value from being changed via the pointer. So I guess `const int *` is already the right choice, just my understanding of const, pointers and templates is insufficient for now.

Comment: Well, if the template parameter `T` is an `int *`, then a `const` of this is `int *const`. That's just how C++ works. You might have to declare a specialization so that when `T` is a pointer, then `get()` does not return `const T`, but the `const` of the type that `T` points to. In any case, a `const` return value doesn't really mean what you think it is. It means that whoever receives the return value can't modify it, and not that whoever receives this return value cannot modify whatever that value points to, if it's a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` version of `int*` is `int* const`, which is a constant pointer to integer type, not pointer to `const int`.

What you intended could be achieved in the following way.

```cpp
template<class T>
struct const_type_handler
{
    using type=const T;
};

template<class T>
struct const_type_handler<T*>
{
    using type=const T*;
};


template <typename T>
class BaseTemplate
{
    public:
        virtual typename const_type_handler<T>::type get() const = 0;
};

class Child : public BaseTemplate<int*>
{
    public:
        Child(int value) : myInt{value} {};
        virtual typename const_type_handler<int*>::type get() const override { return &myInt; };

    private:
        int myInt{0};
};
```

I know this makes the code kinda messy, but it works!.

Comment: can be done slightly shorter with `type_traits`: `using underlying_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_pointer_t<T>, const std::remove_pointer_t<T>*, const T>;`. This will lose cv-qualifiers of `T` if it's a pointer though (which might be intended).

Comment: Definitely an interesting idea. But I think I'll stick to a simpler approach for now. Thanks anyway!